# Will a Tomcat server automatically recognize and enact a cross-domain policy file?

Tags: xml, flash, tomcat, xsd, cross-domain

I have a program that exports .swf files to create dashboards. I'm trying to get it to update dynamically by referencing information included in a (SAP) database, but I'm having issues.

In order to make a specific question (because there are so many things wrong with this program (but I don't have an alternative), and with Flash), I ask the following: When I put a cross-domain policy file (the "Generic XSD" found [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html)) into the Root directory of a Tomcat server, will the server recognize it and use it automatically, or is there something else that I need to do to get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server root directory is not necessarily the root directory of a domain, so you need to put the crossdomain.xml to the root directory of the domain you will be accessing

For example, if you make a call to a script at www.example.com (the script location on that domain doesn't matter) you'd need to put your crossdomain file under www.example.com/crossdomain.xml

Comment: I'm not actually accessing the domain--I'm trying to access/pull data from SAP via a server, so there's no actual domain name to put it in. However, assuming I have the correct directory, it should work without any further action on my part, correct?

Comment: To be honest, I've never worked with SAP but if you access it via HTTP or WebService calls you will always have to specify the server that you want to access. In this case the crossdomain should be at the root of that server name and be accessible via "myServernameOrIPAddress/crossdomain.xml". If you are using these fancy BSP - I have no idea but a quick google for "flash sap crossdomain" brings up a few specific cases and problems :)